# Angular - Interceptor HTTP retornar o valor de uma promisse

Tags: angular, request, return, interceptor

Tenho que aplicar uma `descriptografia` no body do retorno de uma requisição via `Interceptor`, porém o método de descriptografar é assíncrono e retorna uma `promisse`.

Segue um trecho da classe:

```js
intercept(req: HttpRequest, next: HttpHandler): Observable> {

return next.handle(req).pipe(map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
  if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
    let _body;

    this.cryptMethod.decrypt(event.body).this(res => _body = res); // Método assíncrono

    return event.clone({ body: JSON.parse(_body) });

  }
  return event;
}));
}`
```

Acontece que o `this.cryptMethod.decrypt()` é assíncrono, e por isto o return é alcançado antes do _body ser preenchido.

Há alguma solução para isto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente usar uma async function, dessa forma você pode utilizar await dentro da função para esperar o retorno da promise.

```js
intercept(req: HttpRequest, next: HttpHandler): Observable> {

return next.handle(req).pipe(map(async (event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
  if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
    let _body;

    await this.cryptMethod.decrypt(event.body).then(res => _body = res); // Método assíncrono

    return event.clone({ body: JSON.parse(_body) });

  }
  return event;
}));
}`
```

Comment: Valeu cara, funcionou aqui!
obrigado!